# python 2.6 iso datetime parsing error

Tags: python, json, datetime

In python 2.6, why the following code throws "unknown string format" error:

```
import dateutil.parser
import json
from datetime import datetime
dt = dateutil.parser.parse(json.dumps(datetime.now().isoformat()))
```

Comment: What is dateutil? This is not part of the standard library.

Comment: What makes you think `dateutil.parser` should be able to parse a JSON-string (complete with quotes)?

Comment: @Owen: It is an external library, the parser is quite good at recognising different formats. But why the OP feels that a JSON-string should be parseable as a date is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `json.dumps` part, the input into `dateutil.parser.parse` cannot be interpreted:

```
In [6]: json.dumps(datetime.now().isoformat())
Out[6]: '"2013-07-18T12:21:30.278886"'
```

However, without the `json.dumps` part it works:

```
In [7]: dateutil.parser.parse(datetime.now().isoformat())
Out[7]: datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 18, 12, 21, 56, 894926)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because,

```
>>> json.dumps(datetime.now().isoformat())
'"2013-07-18T20:20:48.461835"'
```

Cannot be interpreted by `dateutil.parser`